Dealing with 10-12 yer old impulsiveness
I have 2 sons, aged 10 and 12 and lately they have been dealing with a lot of different things.
So far, their uncle died rather suddenly after Christmas, then my dog died (old age), and now the widowed aunt is living with us, during her grieving period.
Amongst all of this, the boys have had issues with impulsiveness. The 10 year old has always had issues with stealing, which has been reduced to lollies, rather than some of the bigger things he used to steal, but is now not going to sleep - we have to force him to stay in bed, play music, turn the lights off, and monitor that he is actually staying in bed.
The 12 year old has recieved a laptop to be used for school, and has managed to steal the WiFi password, (which I am yet to change, though it was already a custom password - he had retrieved it from his iPad) and claims that it simply "automatically connects" whenever he gets caught using it when he shouldn't. We do allow him to use it for an hour or so after school for homework/assessments, but disconnect him afterwards. (I work in IT so I make sure that he shouldn't be able to access it when he is not allowed).
They have however both grown more impulsive - waking up in the middle of the night to connect to the WiFi, or to play video games in the loungeroom.
They both have an iPad, which is again limited to timeframes of when they can it and how long for. They have also connected this behaviour to the recent events, but they refuse to come to us to talk about it, instead calling "kids helpline" in Australia, to express their oppressed situation. But when we approach them, they state that they don't feel comfortable expressing themselves to us.
For reference, we allow them to use their iPads any time after lunch, until bedtime, but restrict certain things such as YouTube, but allow free access to puzzle games (machinarium) or creative apps (duolingo or "blek") or simple games like relaxing fishing games. During school days this is limited to the afternoons only, before the evening processes begin - afternoon chores, dinner, bedtime process.
Video games are limited to an hour (minecraft, mariokart, Super Smash bros), but we do allow extensions on these based on behaviour.
We express an open household, helping each other with chores, rewards for good behaviour (more free time on devices, or treats, etc), consequencesfor bad behaviour, such as temporarily removing access to the focus of the "crime", like devices for the day, etc. Cooperation, consideration of each other, and communication, different methods to do so, expression of feelings, actions and outcomes, trust... as much as we can, even as gentle reminders such as "10 more minutes then turning it off".
When they get caught out doing the wrong thing, and questioned about it, "why are you doing the wrong thing", they simply repeat back what we have discussed in the past, which means they do listen, but they are not following through on their behaviour and actions; self control bring the current and ongoing issue.
This has all been going on and growing over 4 months, and is reaching the point where my partner and I are looking for alternate solutions, beyond simply punishment or different allowances or complete restiction, alternative activities (the younger one loves lego, and skateboarding, which we greatly encourage; the elder one reads quite a lot and has miniatures that he builds and paints, and we have introduced him to a gaming club so he has company with these activities).

How certain are you that this is indeed an impulsiveness issue?

Based on the info you have provided, this doesn't seem like impulsiveness at all to me. It's just kids being kids, really.
